# PHP register form doesn't insert

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a website where you can register. Now am I aware that when handling user input you must use prepared statements.

Now my problem. On this registration form when I try to register the query does not execute but I don't get any errors either. I have tried back ticks in the query, no back ticks. But to no avail(otherwise I would not ask the question:P).

Could someone say if I am using the right way to check if the query was successful or not?

Here is the HTML form:

```
<form id="register" action="Register.php" name="register" method="post">

     <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label id="lblUsername">Username</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtUsername" name="username" required>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label id="lblEmail">Email</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="txtEmail" name="email" required>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label ID="lblPass">Password</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="password" name="password" ID="txtPassword" required>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <label ID="lblConfPass">Herhaal password</label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="password" name="confpass" ID="txtconfpass" required>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><label id="lblVnaam">Voornaam:</label></td>
                <td><input name="vnaam" type="text" required></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label id="lblAnaam">Achternaam:</label></td>
                <td><input name="anaam" type="text" required></td>
            </tr>    
        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Registreren" required>
        <br />
</form>
```

Here is the PHP part:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', -1);

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "mijnwebsite";

$conn = new mysqli($host,$username,$password,$dbname);


if($conn->connect_errno)
{
    die('Unable to connect to the database. [' . $conn->connect_error . ']');
}



$errors = array();
$data = array();
$fname = $_POST['vnaam'];
$lname = $_POST['anaam'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$confpass = $_POST['confpass'];
$password_hash = crypt($password);

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `User`(`Fname`, `Lname`, `Email`, `Username`, `Password`) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");

$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $fname, $lname, $email, $username, $password_hash);

if(!$stmt->execute())
{
    die("Kon query niet uitvoeren. " . $stmt->error);
}
else
{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert ("Registratie gelukt! klik op oke om door te gaan.");</script>'; 
}

}

?>
```

**Note:** I am going to validate the input but right now I just want to be able to insert.

Thank you guys in advance. Also if there are things that need to be added please leave a comment.

*Edit*: I have changed the error reporting. That was the reason I didn't got any errors back. The Error i got back was:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function password_hash() in
>   /var/www/Register.php on line 140

*Edit 2* : As per Fred -ii- Answer here by i will post my DB structure [image: dbstructure]

*Edit 3:* now that i added the back tick to the end of Username when preparing the query and i added this `if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("There was an error....".$conn->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` I get a different error.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /var/www/Register.php on line 146

*Note 4:* I have updated the code to match the Answer of @Fred-ii- and what is working right now. I want to Thank everybody who has taken time out of their day to help me out.

Comment: "*I don't get any errors either*", are you looking for errors? Take a look at [`error_reporting(-1);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php), [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) and 
[`mysqli_stmt_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error.php)

Comment: Change `display_error` to `display_errors`.

Comment: RTM http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: alright i will change it and report back

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Current PHP version: 5.4.45-0

Comment: `Username, is missing it's end!

Comment: @ChrisG ah good catch on that! I'll make an edit to my answer with credit to you.

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you mate I am wondering how i missed that i checked the query like 3 times. I will update on this matter

Comment: Can people who downvote please leave a comment so i can improve. rogue votes are confusing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per your error in an edit.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function password_hash() in /var/www/Register.php on line 140

There you go. Your version of PHP doesn't support the function. You need to use the password compatibility pack.

https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

You can also look into using `crypt()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

- Make sure that the password column is long enough to hold the hash. A safe best is `VARCHAR(255)`.

You also have (had) a typo in `display_error` and needs to be `display_errors` with an "s". (which you now edited in your question) https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34567204/revisions.

As per the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Edit:

As per Chris G's comment, you have a missing tick for the `Username` column in

```
(`Fname`, `Lname`, `Email`, `Username, `Password`)
                                     ^ right there.
```

Kudos to [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5711970/chris-g)

```
(`Fname`, `Lname`, `Email`, `Username`, `Password`)
```

Error checking on the query http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php would have signaled the error once you've gotten your code to work with the password hashing function that you are able to use.

However, I would replace

```
if(!$stmt->execute())
```

with

`if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("There was an error....".$conn->error, E_USER_WARNING);}`

That may work better for you.

Edit #2:

Another thing I just noticed now; your column names in the query and your screenshot's column names do not seem to match in names.

- `voornaam` and `achternaam` and whether they correspond to `Fname` and `Lname` in our query.

Error checking would have thrown you an error about column mismatch/non-existant, and/or the number of binds do not match.

Edit #3, taken from chat:

Your table is called User but your query's table is Users with an "s".

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfNJY.jpg

Hence the error for:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in /var/www/Register.php on line 146

- You chose the wrong table.

Comment: oh yeah ofcourse i didn't update that in the question will update it right away

Comment: @BRoebie I made a few more edits. One of which states to make sure the password column is long enough to hold the hash. Minimum required is 60, but 255 is better as per what PHP.net suggests to use.

Comment: Holy F*ck how did i mis that. Also i added an image of the db structure

Comment: @BRoebie yeah, Chris had that "Eagle Eye" on that one. Well, I think that once you've configured the compat pack or `crypt()`, you should be good to go.

Comment: @BRoebie I just noticed something now and I will add this to my answer. Your column names in the query and your screenshot's column names do not match in names and I don't know what those other ones mean. an edit has been made at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: i just noticed something it is the wrong db i will update

Comment: @BRoebie it's because of the column names and I've made an edit about it in my answer near the bottom.

Comment: Yeah i saw that i also editted my question to correct my mistake in the image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99535/discussion-between-fred-ii-and-broebie).